# Modify stream in c#

Tags: c#, stream, memorystream, httpserver

I have a simple [http server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httpserver%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) where people upload files and I just compress them and save them to disk. This is what I am doing I think people will understand better with code

```
/// <summary>
/// Client uploads files through here
/// </summary>
private static void Server_ProcessRequest(HttpListenerContext context)
{
    // I know that context.Request.InputStream starts like: ------WebKitFormBoundaryePkpFF7tjBAqx29L
    // and it also ends with that boundary

    // 1. I read from context.Request.InputStream and skip the headers
    // (I read until I find 4 new lines)

    // 2. I then write the file to disk 
    // var sizeOfFile = context.Request.ContentLength64;
    // etc... read from stream

    // 3. create a new stream in order to compress file later
    var newStream = System.IO.File.Open("FileJustCreated");

    // 4. MySealedLibraryThatICannotModify.CompressFile(newStream,"CompressedFileLocation.zip");        
}
```

**So my question in here is how can I avoid writing the file to disk?** I cannot pass `context.Request.InputStream` to the method that compresses the file because it contains header and other stuff that is not part of the file. It will be great if I could create a method that will return a new stream. **The files might be large and I do not want to hold everything on memory** so I was looking to create a method like the `System.IO.File.OpenRead` where it returns a stream where only the part that you read is on memory.

I know I can use a different library to compress the files but it will be nice if I stick to this library and also learn something new.

Comment: The typical approach here would be to wrap one stream with another (custom) stream that tracks the number of bytes consumed and refuses to issue data past this point. You would typically consume the original stream to the desired point before wrapping it. I can probably dig an implementation of this that I have from ancient history if it would help... (I used to do exactly this in protobuf-net)

Comment: phew, took some digging, but: `SubStream.cs`: https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/blob/fd39e2f464273cfe942ab5ab793a7087ae881220/protobuf-net/SubStream.cs

Comment: Why can't you simply pass a partially read stream to `CompressFile`?  Does it actually reset the stream to the start before reading?  I'd think you can just skip to where you want to start using the original stream and pass it in, assuming it reads it in a reasonably sensible manner.

Comment: @Servy typically the problem isn't *starting* at the right point; it is *stopping* at the right place. If the intent is "read from where we are to the end of the file", then sure: nothing extra should be required - just pass the existing stream along

Comment: @MarcGravell The question asks how to skip headers, which I would assume would be at the start.  The question gives me the impression that the parts of the stream to skip are all at the start, rather than the end or somewhere in the middle given the pseudocode (it skips some lines and then just writes the rest of the stream to disk, and then to the 3rd party library).  To the OP, if you need to skip more than just data at the start, could you clarify as much in the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can write into memory instead of a file:

```
using (var buffer = new MemoryStream())
{
    context.Request.InputStream.CopyTo(buffer, sizeOfFile);
    MySealedLibraryThatICannotModify.CompressFile(buffer, path);
}
```

Comment: "The files might be large and I do not want to hold everything on memory "